# How to access Gmail emails in SkyDrive from outlook.com?

Tags: gmail, outlook.com, onedrive

So say you have transferred your emails from Gmails into SkyDrive. How do you access and view or forward them from outlook.com? Any settings to set up?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a page dedicated to explaining the process, including a migration wizard:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/outlook-com/gmail/